# OpenCL Kernel code compile error - Visual Studio 2019

Tags: opencl

I'm kind of new to OpenCL programming and am trying to run a simple vector addition code in VS 2019. However, I can't get the .cl code to compile. It's showing these 6 errors when trying to build the program:

*Error C2144    syntax error: 'void' should be preceded by ';'*

*Error C4430    missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int*

*Error C2065    '__global': undeclared identifier*

*Error  C2146   syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'float4'*

*Error  C2143   syntax error: missing ';' before '{'*

*Error  C2447   '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)*

This is my kernel code:

```
__kernel void add_numbers(__global float4* data,
    __local float* local_result, __global float* group_result) {

    float sum;
    float4 input1, input2, sum_vector;
    uint global_addr, local_addr;

    global_addr = get_global_id(0) * 2;
    input1 = data[global_addr];
    input2 = data[global_addr + 1];
    sum_vector = input1 + input2;

    local_addr = get_local_id(0);
    local_result[local_addr] = sum_vector.s0 + sum_vector.s1 +
        sum_vector.s2 + sum_vector.s3;
    barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

    if (get_local_id(0) == 0) {
        sum = 0.0f;
        for (int i = 0; i < get_local_size(0); i++) {
            sum += local_result[i];
        }
        group_result[get_group_id(0)] = sum;
    }
}
```

I have added the include and lib directories and linked them properly. I couldn't find many fixes for this error after googling. Please help me out...

UPDATE : I fixed it

Hello everyone,
I found the solution to this problem. I removed the .cl file from VS projects and then re-added it (optional). I also changed file open option to have "rb" instead of "r" ( *fopen(filename,"rb")* ). Now I'm able to run it!

Answer (score 0):

Your issue was that the C++ compiler wanted to compile the OpenCL code. You can exclude the file from the VS project and read it with `fstream` at runtime to get the kernel code string, or you can embed the kernel code string right into the executable via stringification macro:

```c
#include <string>
#define R(...) string(" "#__VA_ARGS__" ")
string get_opencl_code() { return R(

// put your OpenCL C code here

);}
```

Comment: Oh, I get it now. Thank you :)