# Recursive include of files in OpenCL source under Xcode

Tags: xcode, include, opencl

I'm looking to build a host program calling OpenCL code running on my GPU device. The cl source has the following form:

```
#include "skip_mwc.cl"
typedef struct{ uint x; uint c; } mwc64x_state_t;
//blah...
```

If I get rid of the `#include` directive and copy/paste the content of "skip_mwc.cl" directly into this source, I can partially "build" and at least get some errors, showing that my compiler (clang9 cl compiler) can at least recognize the kernels code. With the `#include` approach I get the following error:

```
Build log::
<program source>:9:10: fatal error: 'skip_mwc.cl' file not found
#include "skip_mwc.cl"
```

I have checked and the file is there in the search paths, so I'm inclined to believe that my Xcode IDE doesn't index .cl files properly to perform automatic file inclusion (as in .c or .cpp).

I really want to avoid having to copy/paste source from one file into the other. Any suggestions from someone familiar with Xcode, who has encountered this problem and managed to solve it, are very welcome and needed.

Thanks,
A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possible solutions:

1. Set the `-I include_dir` compiler option in `clBuildProgram()`, see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14511140/9178992).
2. Read both files from C++ with `fstream` and string-concatenate their content.

Also see the option of embedding the OpenCL code into the executable via [stringification macro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64313243/9178992).

Comment: I went with approach 2, which works, but was wondering what happens when you have a lot of .cl files for your kernel. One would need to continuously add new files to the string parsing. It would be great if Xcode handled the indexation of these files just as it does for .cpp ones, and directly include them when it sees #include

Comment: There is a way to detect all files with a specific ending like `.cl` in a directory and then automate reading them to strings in a loop. You'd have to give them a specific labeling like `..._1.cl`, `..._2.cl`, ... to make sure the order of concatenation is correct.

Comment: So in effect, there is no way of having Xcode dynamically parsing the content of #include "xxx.cl" called inside another "yyy.cl" file? Things have to be fed to it in a "static" manner.